# How to convert my H2O prediction to a data.frame in a fast way

Tags: performance, dataframe, h2o

I am using H2O, on a large dataset, 8 Million rows and 10 col. I trained my randomForest using h2o.randomForest. The model was trained fine and also prediction worked correctly. Now I would like to convert my predictions to a data.frame. I did this :

```
A2=h2o.predict(m1,Tr15_h2o)
pred2=as.data.frame(A2)
```

but it is too slow, takes forever. Is there any faster way to do the conversion from H2o to data.frame or data.table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code which demonstrates how to use the data.table package on the backend, along with some benchmarks on my macbook:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "16G")
hf <- h2o.createFrame(rows = 10000000)

options("h2o.use.data.table"=FALSE)  #no data.table
system.time(df <- as.data.frame(hf))
# user  system elapsed 
# 224.387  13.274 272.252

options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE)
options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)  # use data.table
system.time(df2 <- as.data.frame(hf))
# user  system elapsed 
# 50.686   4.020  82.946
```

You can get more detailed info when using data.table if you turn on this option: `options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE)`.

Comment: How to set options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE) in python???

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this issue with large prediction datasets when exporting to prediction dataframe or converting them to other types takes long time. I have opened the following JIRA to track it now:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4166

Comment: Thank you for the very fast response. Hope this will be solved this fast too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some new options to turn on using `data.table::fread` to speed it up. Type `h2o:::as.data.frame.H2OFrame` to see the small amount of R source code containing the options, or H2O release notes. Please also try latest `fread` from [dev](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) which is now parallel as of yesterday.

Once users have reported success we can turn the default on by default.