# reading sparse data in h2o using svmlight

Tags: r, data.table, h2o, svmlight

I am trying to read a dataset in SVMLight format into h2o.  Writing it to a file on disk and reading it back is working OK but reading it directly from R's memory is not.  I would like to know if there is a different function or a different way of calling the function I have used below.

Here's an example `R 3.3.3,  h2o 3.10.3.6`:

```
require(data.table)
require(h2o)

set.seed(1000)
tot_obs <- 100
tot_var <- 500
vars_per_obs <- round(.0*tot_var,0):round(.1*tot_var,0)

#randomly generated data
mat.dt <- do.call('rbind', lapply(1:tot_obs, function(n) {
    nvar <- sample(vars_per_obs,1)
    if(nvar>0) data.table(obs=n, var=sample(1:tot_var,nvar))[, value:=sample(10:50,.N,replace=TRUE)]
}))

event.dt <- data.table(obs=1:tot_obs)[, is_event:=sample(0:1,.N,prob=c(.9,.1),replace=TRUE)]

#SVMLight format
setorder(mat.dt, obs, var)
mat.agg.dt <- mat.dt[, .(feature=paste(paste0(var,":",value), collapse=" ")), obs]
mat.agg.dt <- merge(event.dt, mat.agg.dt, by="obs", sort=FALSE, all.x=TRUE)
mat.agg.dt[is.na(feature), feature:=""]
mat.agg.dt[, svmlight:=paste(is_event,feature)][, c("obs","is_event","feature"):=NULL]
fwrite(mat.agg.dt, file="svmlight.txt", col.names=FALSE)

#h2o
localH2o <- h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size="4g")
h2o.no_progress()

#works
h2o.orig <- h2o.importFile("svmlight.txt", parse=TRUE)

#does NOT work
tmp <- as.h2o(mat.agg.dt)
h2o.orig.1 <- h2o.parseRaw(tmp, parse_type="SVMLight")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is that you probably don't have enough R memory to perform this action, so one solution is to increase the amount of memory in R (if that's an option for you).  It could also mean that you don't have enough memory in your H2O cluster, so you could increase that as well.

The only way to go directly from R memory to the H2O cluster is the `as.h2o()` function, so you are definitely using the right command. Under the hood, the `as.h2o()` function writes the frame from R memory to disk (stored in a temp file) and then reads it directly into the H2O cluster using H2O's native parallel read functionality.

We recently added the ability to use **data.table**'s read/write functionality any place that we use base R, so since you have **data.table** installed, you should probably be able to get around this bottleneck by adding this to the top of your script: `options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)`.  This will force the use of **data.table** instead of base R to write to disk for the first half of the `as.h2o()` conversion process.  This should work for you since it's doing the exact same thing that your code is doing already where you use `fwrite` to write to disk and `h2o.importFile()` to read it back in.

Also you don't need the last line with `h2o.parseRaw()`:

```
tmp <- as.h2o(mat.agg.dt)
h2o.orig.1 <- h2o.parseRaw(tmp, parse_type="SVMLight")
```

You can just do:

```
h2o.orig.1 <- as.h2o(mat.agg.dt)
```

There is a related post that shows how to use **data.table** to solve the reverse problem (using `as.data.frame()` instead of `as.h2o()`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865609/how-to-covert-my-h2o-prediction-to-a-data-frame-in-a-fast-way/42965786#42965786).

Comment: I don't think this has to do with memory.  I have tried with "12g" and that does not help.  The code is self contained...try with smaller `tot_obs` and `tot_var`.  Still same issue:  `ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ParseSetup)

water.util.DistributedException
 [1] "DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321, caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: water.fvec.Vec cannot be cast to water.fvec.ByteVec"`

Comment: I tried your other suggestion `options("h2o.use.data.table"=TRUE)` and then `tmp <- as.h2o(mat.agg.dt)`.  I now get the error `Error in h2o.parseSetup(data, pattern = "", destination_frame, header,  : 
  length of col.names must equal to the number of columns in dataset`

Comment: You don't need the last line (I've updated my answer above to clarify that).

Comment: I get the 'h2o.parseSetup' error when I run as.h2o.  Just that line.  Not the next line.

Comment: Is it a h2o version issue?  Does it need a later version?

Comment: The code (without using data.table) works for me on a laptop with 16GB RAM, but I get the same error as you when I use data.table.  I filed a bug report here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4365

Comment: Thx.  It is not really working with the non data.table version either. It is not returning an error.  However the SVMLight is not getting parsed.  I am getting 1 column.  Try running a dim().

Comment: You can certainly try upgrading to the latest version.  I just tried it on a dev version of H2O and had the same bug, so I am assuming the bug is there in the latest stable version as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142868/discussion-between-erin-ledell-and-ironv).